# access CRM Pages through a existing website

Tags: .net, azure, crm

I have a website for a business. From the website I would like to add a link and authentication to CRM 2011 and windows azure. So you need to be able to access CRM Pages through a existing website. Is this possible and would there be any asp.net development required? Please guys any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ADX portal or the CRM SDK. I am sure you will be able to figure it out quite easaly with a quick google search